# Change the settings for a virtualbox snapshot which has children

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, snapshot

I have a disk snapshot in virtualbox, which has some child shapshots, like so:

```
+ Snapshot: After install
`--+ Snapshot: After updates
|  `--+ Snapshot: Installed some software
`--+ Yet another child snapshot...
```

I would like to change some *settings* (**not** the disk's contents) for the snapshot "After install", for example change the amount of RAM from 1Gb to 2Gb. How can I do that apart from creating a new child snapshot of "After install" named, e.g. "After install - 2Gb RAM"?

It seems to me that virtualbox closely couples VM configuration snapshots with disk snapshots, in a needless way. Back when I used QEMU, I could change the settings for each run while still using the same snapshot:

```
qemu -m 1G -hda my-snapshot.qcow2 -cdrom my.iso
qemu -m 2G -hda my-snapshot.qcow2 -some-other-option
```

Comment: What problem do you see there? Since snapshots only register disk differences, the new snasphot (2GB, as you called it) will be very small. From VirtualBox online manual, "Creating the differencing image as such does not occupy much space on the host disk initially, since the differencing image will initially be empty".

Comment: I see two problems: 1) My snapshot list is polluted with old snapshots which shouldn't be used, because they are superseeded by another snapshot with a few configuration tweaks. I don't **want** to see another snapshot in the list, I just want to change an existing one. 2) If a new disk snapshot is created, then it will slow down all disk operations, since it will have to look for the data in more files (but *hopefully* since there aren't any disk changes between the two snapshots, virtualbox will optimize that away).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by editing the .vbox file that in fact is a XML file.

Using eclipse for that is more simple and transparent.

Rename it and make sure to have a backup copy before.

This file contains all snapshots configurations you’re looking for.

I think you’re enough experimented and you don’t need more details ;-)